# Unsure of correct type signature for function using foldr

Tags: haskell

So I have a Database.Persist.TH model defined as the following:

```
share [mkPersist sqlSettings, mkMigrate "migrateAll"] [persistLowerCase|
Transaction json
    date Day
    payee String
    categoryId Int
    memo String
    outflow Double
    inflow Double
    deriving Show Generic
|]
```

I am trying to write a function that will calculate the balance for an account given `[Transaction]`.

So far, I've deduced the following:

```
calculateBalance :: [Transaction] -> Transaction -> Double
calculateBalance [Transaction{..}] = foldr(\x -> transactionInflow - transactionOutflow) (+)
```

This is to say, I think, that we are taking in a list of transactions, using foldr - meaning the list will "deconstruct" to each individual transaction, subtraction will be performed between two doubles, and a `Double` will be returned.

However, something I'm doing seems to be wrong.

One such error is:

```
Couldn't match type ‘Transaction’ with ‘t0 a0’
Expected type: Transaction -> Double
  Actual type: t0 a0 -> Double
In the expression:
  foldr (\ x -> transactionInflow - transactionOutflow) (+)
In an equation for ‘calculateBalance’:
    calculateBalance [Transaction {..}]
      = foldr (\ x -> transactionInflow - transactionOutflow) (+)
```

Yet, changing `calculateBalance :: [Transaction] -> t0 Transaction -> Double` doesn't appear to fix the issue, nor does `calculateBalance :: [Transaction] -> Transaction -> t0 Transaction -> Double`, so I'm a bit confused as for how to proceed.

What might I be doing wrong? Any other tips to make this "idiomatic" Haskell would also be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You have `[Transaction{..}]` in your pattern match, this will only match a single element list of `Transaction`s.  Additionally, you're passing two functions to `foldr`, but it only needs one.  The first argument to `foldr` must take two arguments, but you've given it a lambda that only takes one argument, namely `x`.  The second argument to `foldr` must be the initial value to start with, and the third argument is the list of values to fold over.  I would recommend playing with `foldr` with simpler examples first to get an intuition for how it works, then scaling up to your use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the reason for your error is you do the decomposition of your transaction for a single element list only, and you supply two functions as arguments of `foldr`.

```
calculateBalance = foldr (\t acc -> acc +  transactionInflow t - transactionOutflow t) 0
```

right now I have a meeting - I'll explain some more in an hour or two.

### Edit - Explanations

At first yes you are right the type-signature for your function is not correct.

In the following I will assume that the correct type signature is

```
calculateBalance :: [Transaction] -> Double
```

because you wrote.

> I am trying to write a function that will calculate the balance for an account given `[Transaction]`

- The first thing is that

  ```
  calculateBalance [Transaction{..}] =
  ```

  only matches a singleton list and the `transactionInflow` and `transactionOutflow` provided by the `RecordWildCards` extension only match the values on the left hand side. So the "folding function" is actually a constant one.
- Next is the folding function has the wrong type/is applied to the wrong argument. The type signature for `foldr`

  ```
  foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
  ```

  so the first argument is a function of 2 arguments then the initial-accumulator value comes and then the list is needed.

  - The function argument:

    ```
    (\t acc -> transactionInflow t - transactionOutflow t + acc)
    ```

    the record for `Transaction` creates functions `transactionInflow/transactionOutflow` that can extract the `Double`-value from a `t :: Transaction`. I don't think you can use `RecordWildCards` in a lambda expression, which would save you typing the `t`s which is no biggie I think (if you wanted you could extract the function definition in a `let/where` clause which is rarely a bad idea).
  - Then you need the accumulator value, which is specialized to `Double` by the type constraint given your top level function signature (i.e. has to be the same as the end result).

    ```
    calculateBalance = foldr aux 0
      where aux Transaction{..} acc = acc + transactionInflow - transactionOutflow
    ```

**Note:** if you look at the type signature for `foldr` in `Data.List` in `base` later than 4.8 it is

```
foldr :: Foldable t => (a -> b -> b) -> b -> t a -> b
```

this is due to the [Foldable-Traversable-Proposal (FTP)](https://wiki.haskell.org/Foldable_Traversable_In_Prelude) and is a generalization of the one I listed above, but for `t a = [a]` it acts exactly the same way.

Comment: Thanks so much. I was still getting some type errors when trying to use `transactionInflow t - transactionOutflow t`, so instead I defined a small function `netTransaction :: Transaction -> Double` where `netTransaction t = transactionInflow t - transactionOutflow t`. I then changed the type of `calculateBalance` to `[Transaction] -> Double` and it compiled!